# Using scroll-ID together DOM-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, elementor

i'm using 2 "contact form 7" ony my page and use a DOM-event to pass data from one form to another. Since the form that get's the data is somewhat further down the page, i gave it an anchor/CSS-ID so it would automatically scroll down to the form.

```js
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
if ( '16172' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
location.replace('https://mypage.com/?field1='+jQuery('#field1').val()+'&field2='+jQuery('#field2').val()+'&field3='+jQuery('#field3').val()+'&field4='+jQuery('#field4').val()+'&field5='+jQuery('#field5').val()+'&field6='+jQuery('#field6').val()+'&field7='+jQuery('#field7').val() + '#form');
}
}, false );
```

passing data works fine if i use it without the anchor on the end of the URL, so just "https://mypage.com/". If i add the anchor, it doesn't scroll but also doesn't pass any data.

Any idea how i could get this to work? I'm using the Elementor Pagebuilder (Bridge Theme).

Kind regards

Edit: Try with serialize:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
if ( '16172' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
var parameters = $('#16172).serialize();
location.replace( 'https://mypage.com/?' + $('#16172').serialize() + '#form'); 
}
}, false );
```

Comment: Append the `hashtag' anchor (#form) after your paramter list, to the end or the url-string

Comment: sorry if i don't understand correctly, but what exactly do you mean? It's already on the end of the url-string (https://mypage.com/#form)

Comment: It is before the paramter list. Your url looks sth like this `https://mypage.com/#form?field1=val1&field2=field2` when it should look like this `https://mypage.com/?field1=val1&field2=field2#form`

Comment: I put it right behind the last .val() (see the edit) but now it doesn't even forwards to the second page at all.

Comment: … because you now created a JavaScript syntax error. This would need to be `'&field7='+jQuery('#field7').val()+'#form');`

Comment: (And the whole thing will fail of course, as soon as one of the field values you read there would contain an `&`, for example, or a `#`, because you completely neglected to take care of proper URL encoding here.)

Comment: So i replaced those characters with their encoded values  #23 and #26 but that will fail as well then. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem in your original Question was that your created URL had the `hashtag` - anchor added before your paramter list:

```
location.replace('https://mypage.com/#form?field1='+jQuery('#field1').val()+'&field2='+jQuery('#field2').val()+'&field3='+jQuery('#field3').val()+'&field4='+jQuery('#field4').val()+'&field5='+jQuery('#field5').val()+'&field6='+jQuery('#field6').val()+'&field7='+jQuery('#field7').val());
```

The `hastag` anchor needs to be the last part in your URL - string :

```
location.replace('https://mypage.com/?field1='+jQuery('#field1').val()+'&field2='+jQuery('#field2').val()+'&field3='+jQuery('#field3').val()+'&field4='+jQuery('#field4').val()+'&field5='+jQuery('#field5').val()+'&field6='+jQuery('#field6').val()+'&field7='+jQuery('#field7').val() + '#form');
```

---

To take it a bit further: you can simplify your string creation and take care of url-encoding aswell. Instead of concetenating every single input field to your string with

```
'?field1='+jQuery('#field2').val() + 'field2=' ...
```

you can use `serialize()` on your form element to get an uri encoded string. Exactly what you need:

```
// assuming your from has the id="myform"
var parameters = $('#myForm').serialize();
// creates a string like field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3 ...
```

Now you just need to add your `hastag` anchor and your host:

```
location.replace( 'https://mypage.com/?' + $('#form').serialize() + '#form' );
```

Comment: OK, thanks for going in detail about this. +'#form' works and i get what i did wrong here. But as Cbroe mentioned, it won't pass any content that contains one of the control characters & and #. I tried you suggestion and replaced the "myform" with my contact form 7 ID but it's not working. I put the code in the initial post. What am i missing?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log('URL: ' + $('#16172).serialize());` ?

Comment: It obiously has to be `console.log('URL: ' + $('#16172').serialize());` i did miss the closing `'`

Comment: Now its: "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function". Wonder why since if i look it up, it's the same in the jquery API documentation: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/